# Partial derivative of $f(x,y)=g(2x+5y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function of one variable and let

$f(x,y)=g(2x+5y)$.

How do I find the partial derivative $f_x(x,y)$? I am more interested in an explanation than the result. Which rule (chain rule?) should I use etc., and how?

I know that the answer has form $f_x(x,y)=\text{[some number]}g'(2x+5y)$.

**Update:**

I now get:

$\frac{\partial g(2x+5y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial (2x+5y)}\frac{\partial (2x+5y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g(2x+5y)}{\partial (2x+5y)}2=g'(2x+5y)2$

Is this correct?

Comment: $f(x,y)=g(2x+5y) $ partial derivative of this is$ f_x(x,y)=2 g'(2x+5y)$

Comment: @Boris Why? Don't I have to use the chain rule? I am interested in an explanation more than the result.

Comment: g is also a function of x,y and you must be knowing how to differentiate a function

Comment: @JHStrom Sorry, but I don't see how I am using the chain rule.

Comment: chain rule is used when there is multiplication of two or more functions@akglad

Comment: Is it possible for one of you to create an answer detailing how the chain rule is used for this partial differentiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example:

$f(x)=x^2. $

$f'(x) = 2x.$

$Now, f(2x+5y) = (2x+5y)^2. $

$then, f'(2x+5y) = 2(2x+5y) * \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x+5y) = 2(2x+5y) * 2. $

This is sort of like if I had the original $f'(x)$, then replaced $x$ with $2x+5y$, then multiplied by $2$.

That's due to the chain rule.  You'll notice, since $g(x)$ is a composite function with $2x+5y$, whatever $g(x)$'s derivative originally was, I can get the derivative of the composite function by sticking in $2x+5y$ and then multiplying by the derivative of that (which is $2$).

Comment: Where exactly are you using the chain rule?

Comment: well, the derivative, f'(2x+5y).  The derivative of this function is first 2*(2x+5y), as we multiply the exponent by the term in the parenthesis then subtract one from the exponent.  Then, we take the derivative of the term inside the parenthesis:  partial of 2x+5y is 2.  So, 2(2x+5y) * 2.

Comment: Thanks. Can you see why my textbook says that $g$ is a function of one variable and not two variables?

Comment: That's just arbitrary.  Like in my example, g could originally just be a single variable function, but cramming a 2x+5y where x is will make it a function of two variables.  That's just how composite functions work.

Comment: Is it correct that $f_x(x,y)=\frac{\partial g(2x+5y)}{\partial g(x,y)}\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}$ according to the chain rule?

Comment: Yes.  You'll notice that on the RHS the terms cancel to become $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(2x+5y)$, the same thing you're doing on the left hand side but in Leibniz notation.

Comment: When I use Wolfram Alpha it says that the result is $(2+5y'(x))g'(2x+5y)$. Is that correct? It seems not to be.

Comment: That is technically true if $y$ itself is a function of $x$ and not a variable.  If $y$ IS a variable, as the description of the function as $"f(x,y)"$ would imply, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} y=0$.  That's the danger of Wolfram Alpha, it doesn't necessarily know the difference between what is a variable and what is a function.

Comment: To get the actual result, should I use the chain rule on $g(x,y)$ rather than on $f(x,y)$ as I did earlier and which turned out to be just the original LHS (in another notation)?

Comment: Well, technically g was a function of only a single variable at first.  If we have $g(x,y)$ in the terms of this problem, it is the exact same as $f(x,y)$.  $f(x,y)$ is defined as where we make $g(x)$ into a function of $x$ and $y$ , $( g(x,y) )$.  So, I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around the fact that $g$ is said by my book to be a function of one variable, but it seems to me to be a function of both $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0):

I find differentials easier to calculate with since, unlike partial derivatives, the notation says what it means, and their calculation fairly directly mirrors how you would compute derivatives in single variable calculus; in particular, recall how implicit differentiation works. So I would first compute

$$\mathrm{d} f(x,y)
= \mathrm{d} g(2x + 5y)
= g'(2x + 5y) \mathrm{d}(2x + 5y)
= g'(2x + 5y) (2 \mathrm{d}x + 5 \mathrm{d}y) $$

In terms of differentials, the intent of the notation $f_x(x,y)$ is to refer to the result you get if you compute $\mathrm{d}f(x,y)$ and substitute $\mathrm{d}x \to 1$ and $\mathrm{d}y \to 0$. Thus,

$$ f_x(x,y) = g'(2x + 5y) \cdot 2$$